# How to use global instances in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following in the initializer :

```
options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config','oauth.yml' ))

CLIENT = GameSystem::Client.new options
```

How can i make use of the CLIENT to make calls to its associated methods from the controller ?.

Answer (score 1):

Id do:

```
class ApplicationController

  private

  def game_client
    @game_client ||= begin
      options = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config','oauth.yml' ))
      GameSystem::Client.new options
    end
  end
```

Then call it wherever needed:

```
game_client #like you're using current_user
```

So basically, I'd not create this in an initializer (unless there is a need I can't realize).

Comment: This would load the config file during each request which is probably unnecessary if the file never changes.

Comment: yes...so how would i use it in the initializer so that its available to the entire rails app

Comment: actually this statement sounds weird: `current_user` isn't available to the entire web app and it's just fine, why would you need this?

Comment: If i am not wrong you would need to store that state somewhere other than in an object that's created in the controller; instead, it or an object containing it would ultimately be stored in a static variable somewhere. So we tell consumers to create a  client instance in a Rails initializer and store it in a static variable.